# How to fix the following error: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I'm trying to get some data on my map with a AJAX call. But I get the following error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. I did `console.log(dataArray)`. The thing is that two datasets I implemented in my application before did work and appear on screen but when I tryed to implement my third dataset I got this error and the var `dataArray` stays empty.

```
geojson_popupInfo = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
};

geojson_dataTable = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
};

var dataArray = data.split(", ;");
dataArray.pop();

dataArray.forEach(function(d){
d = d.split(", "); 

var feature_popupInfo = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {}, 
    "geometry": JSON.parse(d[fieldList.length]) 
};

var feature_dataTable = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {}, 
    "geometry": JSON.parse(d[fieldList.length]) 
};

for (var i=0; i<fieldList.length; i++){
    if ([fieldList[i].show_field] == 't') {
        feature_popupInfo.properties[fieldList[i].field_alias] = d[i];
    }
    feature_dataTable.properties[fieldList[i].field_name] = d[i]; 
};
geojson_popupInfo.features.push(feature_popupInfo);
geojson_dataTable.features.push(feature_dataTable);
});
console.log(dataArray)
```

Comment: Make sure each element of array is a valid JSON: `console.log( JSON.parse(d[fieldList.length]) )`

Comment: Can you show us your AJAX call. Without knowing what data and fieldList looks like, we cannot help you.

Comment: Updated the code @Tomasz Nguyen. But the weird thing is that the other 2 datasets work and the last one isn't. (The dataset that is not working is pretty big, but it should be no problem with POST method)

Comment: @L.fcg the code relay on the data you are getting from the ajax response - what is this data? Provide the JSON (the error means the JSON string is invalid)

Comment: "unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1" means there is no data.  Have you confirmed that anything is being returned from the ajax call? (What do you get if you `console.log(data)` inside `getData`'s success handler?)

Comment: When I do that I get back: `(empty text)`. So indeed there's nothing in there. But the weird thing is when I fill in all select fields of my querybuilder it does give a response and appears on the map. I update my question with the getData.php file. @Daniel Beck

Comment: Your php-script returns nothing if `$table` is empty.

Comment: Yep that's the default setting. After that the user makes a selection in a type of querybuilder. And than $table get's selected and the data get's displayed.

Comment: The attributes in your table, are they JSON-values? If so, what is their type?

Comment: Yeah when I fill my select list with the attributes I json_encode them. See my updated question. That's how I fill the select list with attributes.

Comment: I actually meant your database table. Does your query `SELECT $fieldstr FROM $table l ...;` result in rows with JSON data?

Comment: Oww oke, I added my question to show you what I get returned.

Comment: I also added the data when I fill in all the parameters. So table, field, operator and attribute. Why is that working and the other one, when I only select a table isn't?

Comment: I found out what was wrong. The json file is to long and is not getting tottaly send in the POST response. Now I need to find out how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your PHP script outputs JSON and **only** JSON. Right now you're doing:

`echo $attr.", ";`

And later:

`echo json_encode($attribute_names);`

So your output contains both some comma-separated text:

`2, 1, 0, 0, 0, , 0, 0, [snip], 0, 1840, 0, 2,`

and later, some valid GeoJSON:

`{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[6.74578464881977, [snip] ,53.3291017450563]]]]}`

Return (`echo`) **only the GeoJSON, and only once**, do not run any other `echo`s, and you'll be fine.

Comment: It's not the data that is wrong. The JSON response is to long. So the Post Ajax request is not sending back the whole JSON. Now I need to figure out how to increase the JSON length in Xampp I think.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. The problem is that your script output is a mix of JSON and non-JSON data. When you split the output of your script in JavaScript, the JSON is also chunked into parts. As a result, your array `d` does not contain valid JSON anymore.

Normally, we would return pure JSON. In your case, that's hard, because the data in the table contains JSON.

You could go two ways:

1. When you retrieve your data from the table, decode the JSON, create an array of objects from the decoded data, encode the whole array of objects back to JSON, and return it
2. Or don't use commas and semicolons to separate your data, but use some other unique characters or strings such as '|' or 'XYZ' that has no meaning in JSON and that is not a value in the database.